# how to create a pdf file contain different layers

Tags: c++, pdf, layer

I mean using a c or c++ lib. to manipullate. former I use cairo lib, successfully create the pdf file, but no layers. now I want to create  pdf file with several layers.

thanks

Comment: What behavior do you expect from the *layers*? PDF does not explicitly support independent graphics spaces stacked one atop the other. It does know, though, *optional content groups* (collection of graphics that can be made visible or invisible dynamically). Furthermore it allows for multiple content streams of a page which you can try to keep independent from each other by use of the q and Q operators.

Comment: my aim is like you say can control the visible or invisible of a layer. can you explain it in detail?

Comment: I can only point to the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), section 8.11.2 *Optional Content Groups*. I don't know which C++ libs support them, but **OCG support** is what you have to look out for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create (also read and edit) PDF layers (also know an Optional Content Groups) as shown in [PDFLayers](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/samplecode.html#PDFLayers) sample which is also included as part of [PDFNet SDK](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/downloads.html).

The following is a relevant code:

```
    PDFNet.Initialize();
    PDFDoc doc;

    // Create three layers...
    OCG::Group image_layer = CreateLayer(doc, "Image Layer");
    OCG::Group text_layer = CreateLayer(doc, "Text Layer");
    OCG::Group vector_layer = CreateLayer(doc, "Vector Layer");

    // Start a new page ------------------------------------
    Page page = doc.PageCreate();

    ElementBuilder builder; // ElementBuilder is used to build new Element objects
    ElementWriter writer;   // ElementWriter is used to write Elements to the page  
    writer.Begin(page);     // Begin writing to the page

    // Add new content to the page and associate it with one of the layers.
    Element element = builder.CreateForm(CreateGroup1(doc, image_layer.GetSDFObj()));
    writer.WriteElement(element);

    element = builder.CreateForm(CreateGroup2(doc, vector_layer.GetSDFObj()));
    writer.WriteElement(element);

    // Add the text layer to the page...
    if (false)  // set to true to enable 'ocmd' example.
    {
        // A bit more advanced example of how to create an OCMD text layer that 
        // is visible only if text, image and path layers are all 'ON'.
        // An example of how to set 'Visibility Policy' in OCMD.
        Obj ocgs = doc.CreateIndirectArray();
        ocgs.PushBack(image_layer.GetSDFObj());
        ocgs.PushBack(vector_layer.GetSDFObj());
        ocgs.PushBack(text_layer.GetSDFObj());
        OCG::OCMD text_ocmd = OCG::OCMD::Create(doc, ocgs, OCG::OCMD::e_AllOn);
        element = builder.CreateForm(CreateGroup3(doc, text_ocmd.GetSDFObj()));
    }
    else {
        element = builder.CreateForm(CreateGroup3(doc, text_layer.GetSDFObj()));
    }
    writer.WriteElement(element);

    // Add some content to the page that does not belong to any layer...
    // In this case this is a rectangle representing the page border.
    element = builder.CreateRect(0, 0, page.GetPageWidth(), page.GetPageHeight());
    element.SetPathFill(false);
    element.SetPathStroke(true);
    element.GetGState().SetLineWidth(40);
    writer.WriteElement(element);

    writer.End();  // save changes to the current page
    doc.PagePushBack(page);

    // Set the default viewing preference to display 'Layer' tab.
    PDFDocViewPrefs prefs = doc.GetViewPrefs();
    prefs.SetPageMode(PDFDocViewPrefs::e_UseOC);

    doc.Save("my.pdf", SDFDoc::e_linearized, 0);
```

Note: I am a PDFNet developer.

Comment: thanks，it‘s a trial version. the former version may need commercial license.